# AJAX CalenderExtender Not Working

Tags: asp.net, calendarextender

I am using ajax calender extender on my website.

```
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Active From: <asp:TextBox ID="inputActiveFromDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
                                                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="inputActiveFromDate" PopupButtonID="btn_Calendar1"   Format="dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
                                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btn_Calendar1" ImageUrl="../images/buttons/Lock_icon.gif" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="20"></td>
                                            <td>Active Until: <asp:TextBox ID="inputActiveUntilDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="inputActiveUntilDate"  PopupButtonID="btn_Calendar2"  Format="dd/MM/yyyy 23:59:59"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
                                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btn_Calendar2" ImageUrl="../images/buttons/Lock_icon.gif" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

everything is working fine, but i am getting this error on all the browsers.

```
> Unable to set value of the property 'PopupBehavior': object is null or
> undefined
```

please help me to solve

Error comes at

```
// Name:        MicrosoftAjax.debug.js
// Assembly:    AjaxControlToolkit
// Version:     4.1.50508.0
// FileVersion: 4.1.50508
// (c) 2010 CodePlex Foundation

initialize: function Behavior$initialize() {
        Sys.UI.Behavior.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');
        var name = this.get_name();
        if (name) this._element[name] = this;// error place <---
    },
```

MY CS CODE:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"].ToString())){

String  sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (SDate,EDate) VALUES ('" + Convert.ToDateTime(inputActiveFromDate.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToDateTime(inputActiveUntilDate.Text) + "'); SELECT  @@IDENTITY;";conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);    
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   // int lastId = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
                    conn.Close();




                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is because of you are using the PopupButtonID option and passing in the textbox id

You either need to remove this option or pass in an id of an actual button

```
<asp:TextBox ID="inputActiveUntilDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="inputActiveUntilDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy 23:59:59"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

OR

```
<asp:TextBox ID="inputActiveUntilDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="inputActiveUntilDate" PopupButtonID="btn_Calendar" Format="dd/MM/yyyy 23:59:59"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btn_Calendar" ImageUrl="PathToACalendarButton" />
```

**Edit:**

I dont know much about sql injection risks, but it seems to me that it could be definitely be possible in your code. You may want to think about using parameterized queries such as stored procedures.

Comment: Removing the "PopupButtonID" did solved the break on page load. However , when submitting the Date entry in the database , it again breaks. I tried both of your solutions.

Comment: How does it break at that point? It obviously isnt the same error. So you need to give more information.

Comment: It might also be helpful to see how you are trying to save it into the database. The control could be working just fine, you could be trying to retrieve the result or save it improperly.

Comment: i have edited my question with more information. I am still getting the same error on the IE debugger on the specified line.

Comment: CalendarExtender  is in the update panel ..and on removing the update panel it works fine....so, issue i think is with update panel and ajax control ..

Comment: The AjaxControlToolkit works fine with an UpdatePanel. I have several sites where I have used them together. Are you receiving a new error? I dont see how it could be the same one.